# модальное окно Gui Tkinter python 2.7

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Здравствуйте. Имеется программа на python 2.7 с GUI Tkinter, она отображает ФИО человека и его фото, вопрос в следующем, как сделать так, что бы фото открывалось в новом окне(по верх окна с текстом) с определёнными размерами. Ну и что бы с начало отображался текст, а потом окно с фото.

код:

```
from Tkinter import *
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
app.title(u"Информация")
app.geometry("450x120+100+0")
label1 = Label(font = 'Arial 11',text='  '+u'Фио:'+'   '+'Иванов И.И')
im = PIL.Image.open("C:\lol.jpg")
ph_im = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
panel = Label(app, image = ph_im)
panel.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = "no")
panel.grid()
label1.grid()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

[Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) + [transient](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.transient-method)

пример для python3

```
import tkinter as tk

def top_wind():
    top = tk.Toplevel()  # что бы фото открывалось в новом окне
    top.transient(root)  # по верх окна с текстом
    top.geometry('{}x{}'.format(200, 50))  # с определёнными размерами
    top.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    top.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (root.winfo_rootx(), root.winfo_rooty()))  # по верх окна с текстом
    tk.Label(top, text='фото').pack()  # фото

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Text(root, height=10, width=30).pack()  # что бы с начало отображался текст
root.after(10, top_wind)   # а потом окно с фото
root.mainloop()
```